# Getting total result count and allowing pagination in the same query with MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have my query set up like so to allow for pagination. While this works, I have to basically run the same query twice to get the total matching results for the query AND allow for pagination. Is there any way to combine this into a single query?

```
public SearchResult GetResults()
{
    //query is built elsewhere
    var totalResults = (from i in Collection.Find(query)
        select i).Count();

    var results = (from i in Collection.Find(query)
        select i)
        .Skip(recordsToSkip)
        .Take(recordsToTake)
        .ToList();

    //SearchResult is defined elsewhere
    return new SearchResult
    {
        Results = results,
        TotalResults = totalResults
    };
}
```

Comment: FYI depending on your page size you can have multiple round trips to the mongodb server too, results are returned in batches and as enumeration exhausts a batch, a new batch will be retrieved. And as such, I think worrying about two round trips, one for a count and one for the items, is probably not a concern unless you have a huge amount of latency.

Comment: Almost no latency, the app and DB are on the same server. It's not really a performance bottleneck, it just feels like a hacky way to do it, but I guess it's not worth worrying about too much

Comment: This is pretty typical for pagination with any DB. I tend to not optimize for performance until it's necessary.

Answer (score 5):

First, to get the count you should not do a linq query and then count the results. This way enumerates all the results and then counts them, which is costly. You should instead use:

```
var totalResults = Collection.Find(query).Count()
```

This `Count` method is defined on the `MongoCursor` itself and will count the results in mongo, instead of in your .Net application.

I guess that was the real problem behind the question. But if you still want to unite the 2 queries you can do that like so:

```
var results = (from i in Collection.Find(query) select i).ToList();
var totalResults = results.Count();
var page = results
    .Skip(recordsToSkip)
    .Take(recordsToTake)
    .ToList();
```

That will get the whole collection, count it, and return a page of it. I would not recommend you do that though, because you don't need the whole collection.

P.S: When you use Linq on the result of Find, it does the filtering in your application and not in the DB, so you should change your query to this one:

```
var results = Collection.Find(query)
    .SetSkip(recordsToSkip)
    .SetLimit(recordsToTake)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Even if I were to change it to `Collection.AsQueryable<T>().Count()`, I'd still have to run the query twice. True, returning a cursor doesn't load any of the results into memory, so it would be faster on the application side, but I'd still be hitting the DB twice to get the paged results as well as the total count

Comment: @Jedediah that's true, but you can't simply join 2 queries to 1. you can do what i showed in the second block and get the whole collection at once. That would result in only a single query against the DB. So you can do it in 1 query or 2, but 2 would be better (even for the DB)

Comment: @Jedediah I added another tip for you. This solution will probably greatly improve your performance.